# close all open folders in file explorer using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to create a bat file that can close all open folders in the file explorer. However, it should not close any programs that are open (for example: excel, outlook, web browsers etc). Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn [ask] here as your "question" is off-topic here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `wmic` to find all `explorer.exe` processes with `-Embedding` in their command line and terminate those. This should skip the shell since it doesn't have `-Embedding` in its command line.

```
wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like '%\\explorer.exe % -Embedding'" Call Terminate
```

As Compo pointed out in the comments: For this to work in a batch file, you need to double the percent signs:

```
wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like '%%\\explorer.exe %% -Embedding'" Call Terminate
```

Comment: From a [tag:batch-file], the wildcards, _percent characters_, require doubling.